# SensorKinect not installing?

Tags: windows-8, github, kinect, sensors, openni

I was recently following a tutorial in a "Kinect Hacking" book that I purchased on Amazon. The first thing I was asked to do, is to check to see if my Kinect plug would fit into my laptop's which it did. I was then asked to download OpenNI from the following link: http://www.openni.org/Downloads/OpenNIModules.aspx

The only problem is that the link given above redirects to a "unknown page" (which is probably due to a recent site update...Anyway, I download OpenNI from here instead: http://www.openni.org/openni-sdk/ (for Windows), and it installed fine, though after then asked to additionally install Sensor Kinect from the following link: https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect (that link did work) and executing the .exe file, I received an error message saying to: "Please install OpenNI version 1.2.0.4 or higher!"

So...what should I do?
Thanks in advance! (I haven't had any help on the OpenNI forums, so I posted here). 
**P.S I'm running Windows 8**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently I'm not the only one with this problem, and after some research I found that the new OpenNI isn't compatible with the SensorKinect, so in order to fix this I have to download the version that is slightly dated, luckily a site called "ZigFu" has all the necesary plugins built onto one: http://zigfu.com/en/downloads/browserplugin/